# How to diagnose MSSQL high CPU spike

Tags: sql-server

I've had my server CPU spiked to 100% for about 20 minutes. The database was partially unresponsive in certain parts.( i know this because users complained that they cant use certain features, but they could login, and use other areas, only not specific). Before I could check current queries it was gone. I want to see what was the cause of it. Does anyone have some kind of instructions on this? How do I actually get to the root cause of this. How to see what query caused this?  I am using MSSQL

edit:
I found in RING BUFFER LOGS which record id and at what time CPU spiked. Is this something that can bring me to root of issue ?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have something that captured the queries being executed at the time, all you can do is guess.  In case you're on SQL Server 2016 or higher, and you have Query Store enabled for the affected database, I'll mention that you could track down long-running or slow queries there.  If you don't have query store or some other way of tracking activity after a problem, you might want to look into a monitoring tool, or at least some simpler "home grown" solutions, like logging `sp_WhoIsActive` to a table.

If the queries that caused this problem are still in the plan cache, you could try [running `sp_BlitzCache`](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit#sp_blitzcache-find-the-most-resource-intensive-queries) to find the most CPU-intensive queries:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_BlitzCache 
    @DatabaseName = N'YourDatabaseName',
    @SortOrder = 'avg cpu';
```

To be clear, there's no way to know for sure if those queries are the problem ones, but it might be your best bet at this point.

You could also try to narrow down the tables involved (based on which areas of the application or features you said you know were inaccessible).  Once you've done that, you could [run `sp_BlitzIndex`](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit#sp_blitzindex-tune-your-indexes) on that table and get a breakdown on how it's being used:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_BlitzIndex 
    @DatabaseName = N'YourDatabaseName', 
    @SchemaName = N'ProbablyDbo', 
    @TableName = N'YourTableName';
```

That will show you if there are indexes being scanned a lot, or experiencing lock escalation, or long lock waits, etc.  Again, this would all be sort of circumstantial evidence of potential problems.  But it might help.

Answer (score 0):

When you see 100% you are seeing a snapshot from Os Perspective: It takes a sample of process total CPU, waits for 1 second(default), takes another sample, and shows you this diff (and some tools can also divide by total CPU to calculate an average).

So, if you cannot collect what running at the time of CPU 100%, is very hard to get what causing your CPU to work hard.

My tips:

- Use sp_whoisactive @delta_interval = 1,@sort_order = '[CPU_delta] DESC' to find queries spending most CPU at that time interval you are looking for.
- Start a XE or profiler during high CPU, collect all queries running without any filter by some seconds (e.g: 5 seconds). Export this to the table, groups by the query, and try to find a query that most consumed CPU in this interval. Take caution with this, depending on your workload, you can experience some impacts.

Find the queries spending CPU is not so simple... You can have 1 query running in parallel, or you can have a lot of small queries (running less than 100ms, for example)... My experience shows that using Extended Events/profiler to get all is better to found if the problem is a lot of queries running less than 1 second... For other cases, whoisactive must help you.